# On screen keyboard doesn't change with language

Tags: 20.04, ibus, onscreen-keyboard, korean

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed two languages English and Korean. I turned on **On Screen Keyboard.** But when I change language to Korean and use the on screen keyboard, it still shows English alphabet only, clicking buttons enters English characters only if using default input method **ibus**(With **scim** it has a new input Korean(Hangul) which inserts Korean Characters).However still On Screen Keyboard only shows English Characters. Am I missing any setting or is it a bug? Ideally, it should show korean characters when I switch to Korean.

P.S. Earlier I had posted about this bug in Pop OS and it was closed, So I tested with Ubuntu and same issue was present.

Also I tested with another language(Arabic) in Ubuntu, it works perfectly fine.